# SQL complex query- ORDER BY and GROUP BY in the same query did not work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like that,
[image]

Now, I want to find out the winner, who gave the correct answer most in early. I tried something like that,

```
SELECT COUNT(is_correct), msisdn 
FROM [robi_contest].[dbo].[tbl_quiz_reply] 
WHERE is_correct = 1 group by msisdn
```

And output is-
[image]

Now, When I try to ORDER BY creation_time , it did not give expected out but error. What should be the query to find out the winner.

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: "it did not give expected out but error." If you get an error, at least share the error message. What do you expect to happen? You want to sort by an attribute you are not selecting, but are aggregating over. How would the order look like?

Comment: Sample data would be much better appreciated as a table variable and insert statement, *as text*, with extraneous columns removed. We don't need the typing practice, thanks. Also, try to make sample data that is short but includes the edge cases you're trying to deal with, and then also show us the *expected results*, ideally also *as text*.

Comment: I am using sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(is_correct), msisdn , min(creation_time) as min_creation
FROM [robi_contest].[dbo].[tbl_quiz_reply] 
WHERE is_correct = 1 group by msisdn
order by min_creation
```

The problem is that you were not returning the column as part of the group. Applying a min() to the column allows you to order by the first occurence by isdn.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(is_correct), msisdn 
FROM [robi_contest].[dbo].[tbl_quiz_reply] 
WHERE is_correct = 1 
group by msisdn 
order by max(msisdn) or Min(msisdn)
```

Try ordering by Max or min Which ever you want

Comment: It's giving - Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(is_correct), msisdn 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_quiz_reply WHERE is_correct = 1 ORDER BY creation_time DESC) as test
group by msisdn
```

Comment: It give something like that,Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Can you give SQL Fiddle Demo? So I can Help you.

Comment: @Sadikhasan Basically, you can't put an `order by` in the subquery without putting a `TOP n` in there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
       msisdn , COUNT(is_correct) AS NumberOfCorrectAnswers,
       max(creation_time) AS LastCorrectAnswerDatetime
FROM [robi_contest].[dbo].[tbl_quiz_reply] 
WHERE is_correct = 1 
GROUP BY msisdn
ORDER BY COUNT(is_correct) DESC, max(creation_time) ASC
```